# How to add two columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, addition

I have come across a very strange problem. I am trying to add two columns of a Pandas Dataframe, but the result is wrong for a row.

I am working on Python 3.

The following works for every column except one:

```
df['col3'] = df['col1']+df['col2']
```

When col1 has a value of 3 and col2 has 0, the output in col3 comes out to be 0 instead of 3!
All the data types are either `int64` or `float64`

Here is an image of the dataframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/te1Ey.jpg

Comment: Please provide a text representation of the example dataframe, `df = pd.DataFrame(...)`

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: I am trying to reproduce it as well, but cannot. 
Somehow all the rows are added properly, except this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRACKED IT!!! I HAVE BEEN SO SILLY! 
But I will still keep the post up since it can happen to someone in the future!

What I was doing: 
*(It a long script of many dataframes and columns and mapping one column to another...)*

While filling in data to col2, `df.col2.iloc[7] = nan`. 
I had completely missed this. 
Therefore when I add `df.col1.iloc[7] + df.col2.iloc[7] = nan`. 
The next step in the script, changes every `nan` value to ZERO!

Hence, `3+0 = 0`!!

I apologize for not being able to share the script, but still, appreciate all the help!